# How do i prevent my canvas from crashing my browser

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Why does this code make my visual studio live preview and browser go mad when I change the width or height of canvas? Sometimes it works after refreshing page a few times or closing and opening live preview but I can't get why it makes everything go crazy.

When I put height and width and the same ratio of 400 everything works but when I change it for example for 300 for both it goes crazy. It should have worked for any height or width.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      canvas {
        border: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
        border-radius: 3em;
        padding: 40px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        function drawPixels(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, pixelSize, color) {
          const dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
          const dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
          const sx = x1 < x2 ? 1 : -1;
          const sy = y1 < y2 ? 1 : -1;
          let err = dx - dy;
          let x = x1;
          let y = y1;
          while (true) {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, pixelSize, pixelSize);
            if (x === x2 && y === y2) break;
            const err2 = 2 * err;
            if (err2 > -dy) {
              err -= dy;
              x += sx * pixelSize;
            }
            if (err2 < dx) {
              err += dx;
              y += sy * pixelSize;
            }
          }
        }
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var pixelSize = 20;
        var rectWidth = canvas.width;
        var rectHeight = canvas.height;
        canvas.height += pixelSize;
        var sq = Math.min(rectHeight, rectWidth);
        console.log(sq);
        var x1 = 0;
        var y1 = sq;
        var x2 = sq / 2;
        var y2 = 0;
        var x3 = sq;
        var y3 = sq;
        drawPixels(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, pixelSize, "red");
        drawPixels(ctx, x2, y2, x3, y3, pixelSize, "red");
        drawPixels(ctx, x3, y3, x1, y1, pixelSize, "green");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which of the gazillion browsers/versions are you using?

Comment: It doesn't cost any money to hit the space bar every once in a while.

Comment: @Pointy sorry stackoverflow formating rules confused me a little bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canvas isn't crashing the browser, the `while` loop is. JS is single-threaded, which means your code needs to yield to the browser so it can repaint and process interactions. If you have code that blocks the repaint for less than a hundred milliseconds or so, the user may not notice. If you have code that blocks the rendering loop for more than a few seconds, the page might hang or be considered unresponsive by the browser. If you have code that never lets a repaint run, perhaps due to an infinite loop, the page will never become responsive again and will probably run your CPU at 100% until the page is forceably killed. The last case is happening here.

How do debug this? One way is to check your loop termination condition:

```js
// this is one thing to look for when your page doesn't respond
while (true) {

  // add this so you can understand why `break` is unreachable
  console.log({x, x2, y, y2});

  // this stops the loop, but is never true for 300x400
  if (x === x2 && y === y2) break;
}
```

If I open the dev tools and run your page, I see the console spammed with crazy values like `{ x: 477400, x2: 150, y: -954500, y2: 0 }`, clearly not what you intended to happen.

It seems `drawPixels` is a line-drawing algorithm of some sort, probably [Bresenham's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm), but your implementation isn't accounting for step sizes that might overshoot the destination. You could isolate exactly when the overshoot happens by checking when `x` and `x2` and `y` and `y2` are fairly close rather than perfectly equal. Examining the values at this critical moment of failure could be useful.

To make debugging easier, consider using a single-step debugger, or converting your `while (true)` loop temporarily to a finite loop with plenty of room for the algorithm to complete:

```js
// if 10_000 spams too much, you can decrease this number and run
// the code again to stop the algorithm at a critical point
let tries = 10_000;

while (tries--) {
  // ... your algorithm and debugging logs here
}
if (tries <= 0) {
  console.log("infinite loop detected");
}
```

If you're working from a known algorithm, possibly provided as pseudocode, now is a good time to double-check that you've translated it correctly.

Now that you know what the problem is and you've gained some techniques for [isolating the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [debugging small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), you're equipped to fix the bug and complete the algorithm you're trying to implement.

If you're not trying to learn algorithms and just want to draw a line, then consider using [`ctx.lineTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo) rather than reinventing the wheel.